# Remove comma from parsed string before convert it to double

Tags: regex, scala

```
val value = "€1,172"
val parsed = value.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}", "")
```

My parsed value is now `1,172` and i want to convert it to double so i need to remove the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have already used `replaceAll` what was the problem. You have to use

```
val value = "€1,172"
val parsed = value.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}", "").replaceAll(",", "").toDouble
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/RMybOk)**

As suggested by [noob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705585/noob), you can also use `alternation`

```
val value = "€1,172.46"
val parsed = value.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}|,", "").toDouble
```

Comment: This is clever and could combine both replace into one using [alteration](https://regex101.com/r/mI9dD5/1).

Comment: @noob Updated as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1 - no replacements, just joining.

```
val regex = "[(\\d*)(?:.)*?](\\.\\d{0,2})?"
val result = regex.r.findAllIn(value).mkString("")
```

Approach #2 - replacements, no joining.

```
val regex = "[^\\d(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?]"
val result = regex.r.replaceAllIn(value, "")
```

The difference between your original code and mine is that I am trying to account for a decimal ending possibly.

The decimal is meaningful in that case (and locale) and you cannot just chop it off - could be $100 different.

So in my second example, you see I allow two types of things - decimals, and strings terminating with DOT DECIMAL DECIMAL

Answer (score 0):

Use `filterNot` on a set of characters to exclude,

```
value.filterNot(Set('€', ',')(_))
```

The string in Scala is treated here as a sequence of characters so we can apply filtering at character level. The condition is on set inclusion.